# How to convert slow cooker recipes to pressure cooker with different cooking times?

Tags: equipment, meat, vegetables, slow-cooking, pressure-cooker

Google results for this question either don't answer the question at all or don't address what happens when multiple ingredients have different pressure cooking times. I'm specifically looking to convert this recipe:

[image]

[This site](http://busycooks.about.com/cs/appliances/a/pressurecooker.htm) says if it takes 8 hours in the slow cooker, it'd take 1 hour in the pressure cooker. Okay, but the recipe involves parsnip and turnip, which my pressure cooker manual says to cook for 1-2 and 3-5 minutes, respectively. I have a 4 quart Presto pressure cooker that goes up to 15 psi which I believe is the standard pressure.

1. Is there a better conversion rule than 8 hour -> 1 hour (assuming 15
   psi)? In my experience, at 15 psi, stew beef would fall apart after
   only 30'.
2. What do I do about the different cooking times? Am I supposed to
   cook the meat by itself for 1 hour, quick-release the pressure under
   cold running water, add the turnips, bring the cooker back to
   pressure, quick-release again, add the parsnips, and finally bring
   the cooker back to pressure again?

Answer (score 6):

There is no rule, you should use the cooking times in your chart or a reputable timing chart, I use this one [hippressurecooking.com/pressure-cooking-times](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/pressure-cooking-times/)

Basically, you'll want to phase-in the ingredients. That means, cook the beef roast for the time your cooking chart says, say 30 minutes, then open the pressure cooker and add the vegetables and pressure cooker them for their cooking time 4 minutes.

BTW, that same blog has a section where you can post a recipe and they will convert it to the pressure cooker for you. That's here: [hippressurecooking.com/recipe-conversions](http://www.hippressurecooking.com/forums/forum/recipe-conversions/)

Comment: Yup. I use this site and their pressure cooking times. So far, all that I've used have been bang on.

I've also made stews in the pressure cooker and do what Dana recommended - cook the meat for a while, release pressure and open, add potatoes & carrots, bring back up to pressure, and so on. If there are softer veggies added at the end that only require a few minutes to cook, I'll finish the stew stovetop not under pressure.